# JIRA java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: tomcat, jira, permgen

I am running JIRA from war file on Win7.

1) Java 6

2) Tomcat 6

3) Jira 5

I installed JIRA yesterday. I was able to get into JIRA web application yesterday and was configuring JIRA, until I entered licence key and TomCat gave me PermGen space error.

So far I have been trying googleing for hours and trying stuff, but nothing seems to work. At the moment I have this snippet in my tomcat->catalina.sh file. Yes I tried putting this to setenv.sh(bat) file, but still same error. So far have not been able to get Jira up and running again.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Error:

```
2012-06-02 12:02:52,821 main INFO      [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Plugin Unit: C:\JIRA\home\plugins\.bundled-plugins\streams-api-5.1.0.jar (1337537820000) created
2012-06-02 12:02:52,828 main INFO      [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Plugin Unit: C:\JIRA\home\plugins\.bundled-plugins\streams-core-plugin-5.1.0.jar (1337537822000) created
2012-06-02 12:02:52,839 main INFO      [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Plugin Unit: C:\JIRA\home\plugins\.bundled-plugins\streams-inline-actions-plugin-5.1.0.jar (1337537822000) created
2012-06-02 12:02:52,845 main INFO      [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Plugin Unit: C:\JIRA\home\plugins\.bundled-plugins\streams-jira-inline-actions-plugin-5.1.0.jar (1337537822000) created
2012-06-02 12:02:53,068 main INFO      [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Plugin Unit: C:\JIRA\home\plugins\.bundled-plugins\streams-jira-plugin-5.1.0.jar (1337537820000) created
2012-06-02 12:02:53,083 main INFO      [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Plugin Unit: C:\JIRA\home\plugins\.bundled-plugins\streams-spi-5.1.0.jar (1337537822000) created
2012-06-02 12:02:53,093 main INFO      [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Plugin Unit: C:\JIRA\home\plugins\.bundled-plugins\streams-thirdparty-plugin-5.1.0.jar (1337537822000) created
2012-06-02 12:02:53,113 main INFO      [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Plugin Unit: C:\JIRA\home\plugins\.bundled-plugins\workflow-designer-plugin-2.5.5.jar (1337537818000) created
2012-06-02 12:03:01,127 Spring executor 1 INFO      [plugins.monitor.rrd4j.RrdUpdater] Reusing existing RrdDb: C:\JIRA\home\monitor\ConnectionPoolGraph.rrd4j
2012-06-02 12:03:01,220 Spring executor 1 INFO      [plugins.monitor.rrd4j.RrdUpdater] Reusing existing RrdDb: C:\JIRA\home\monitor\DatabaseReadWritesGraph.rrd4j
2012-06-02 12:03:01,319 Spring executor 1 INFO      [jira.plugins.monitor.MonitoringScheduler] Scheduling metrics collector to run every 10000ms...
2012-06-02 12:03:50,998 Spring executor 4 WARN      [beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] FactoryBean threw exception from getObjectType, despite the contract saying that it should return null if the type of its object cannot be determined yet
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Notice the Tomcat stops for 49 seconds on "Scheduling metrics collector to run every 10000ms...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running **Tomcat as service** from apache-tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe, **open up Tomcat GUI** from tomcat6w.exe and add following line to Java Options in Java tab:

-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: @alain.janinm : yup :) just after 2 days.